# How to get WSDL file - William Hill SOAP APIs

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am working on a non-commercial project and trying to use William Hill APIs to get a list of sports and odds for a few markets.

I am using an old version of the API since it's public, while the [new version](https://developer.williamhill.com/v2/api/sportsdata-api) is protected by an API Key that they [do not distribute anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOvTk.png).

I have found the entry endpoint that gives me all the available categories:

- http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn

Using the category ID in that response I am able to access the odds for specific markets - eg. basket:

- http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=336&marketSort=--&filterBIR=N

The problem is that this API is quite slow (takes between 5 and 60 seconds to return results depending on the category) so I would like to add some filters to the request in order to reduce the size of the results.

How can I retrieve the WSDL file that describes the available query parameters / arguments?

I tried to add `?WSDL` or `?wsdl` to the entry endpoin since AFAIK that's the standard way but I had no success.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a question you will have to ask William Hill support.

Comment: I will try, thanks :) -- PS. There isn't a support section specific for their APIs so I suspect that through the usual ways it will take some time, let's see how it goes :) https://williamhillplc.com/site-services/contact-us

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?